# Is there a way to find google search results for a certain keyword with javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, google-search

I am looking for a way to find search results from google with javascript.

Comment: scrap it using html agility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Google's api to fetch search result from Google.

But for that you have to get a API key from Google and then you can use google's api to fetch result.

Please check this [official link](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest) to know example and more.

Here is an example http get request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures
```

you can simply request these http get request from your javascript using `ajax`.
In the above example you can replace the word **lectures** with the key word that you want to search.

You can find complete reference of using Javascript to request google's api [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js).