# Search for particular link in google search

Tags: javascript, google-search

```
<body>

<form action="http://google.com/search" method="GET">
    <label for="keyword">Keyword: </label>
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Keyword" id="keyword">

    <label for="site">Site: </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Site" id="site">


    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" onclick="well();">
</form>

<script >
    function well(){
        var something = document.getElementById("site").value;
        alert(something);
    }
</script>
```

So What I want is that:

1. In the first Input you search a keyword that you want to search on google.
2. In second Input you put the link you want to search to see wether it appears on first page or not
3. With click of button make it search and make my script work on that page.

   ```
   var myList = [];
   var x = document.querySelectorAll("#rso h3");
   for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
   myList.push(x[i].textContent);
   }
   console.log(myList);
   ```

And This above code can do that finding of h3 tags.

But how can I make that happen with the click of button?

Answer (score 0):

A form action with the google.com url will navigate your user away from your site and to that search. In order to capture the search results, you'll need to use the [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest). Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896175/is-there-a-way-to-find-google-search-results-for-a-certain-keyword-with-javascri)